# Solving the system of recurrence relatioin

Tags: recurrence-relations

Given the recurrence system:
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
   T_n = T_{n-1} + S_n, &\\
   S_n = T_{n-1} + S_{n-1} &
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

And we know $T_0 = 1, S_0 = 0$.

***I tried to solve it the following way:***

Using generating functions I represent the system as
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
   \mathfrak{T}(t) - 1 = \mathfrak{T}(t) + \mathfrak{S}(t), &\\
   \mathfrak{S}(t) = \mathfrak{T}(t) + \mathfrak{S}(t) &
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

But solving obtained system of equation I conclude that $\mathfrak{T} = 0$ and $\mathfrak{S} = -t$.
It seems wrong for me. Possibly is my way of solving wrong?

Comment: By the way, it looks like Fibonacci numbers
$F_0 = S_0, F_1 = T_0, F_2 = S_1, F_3 = T_1$, and so on

Answer (score 0):

Use generating functions, $S(z) =  \sum_{n \ge 0} S_n z^n$ and similarly $T(z)$. Shift indices:

$\begin{align}
  S_{n + 1} &= S_n + T_n \\
  T_{n + 1} &= S_{n + 1} + T_n
\end{align}$

Multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$ and recognize the resulting sums:

$\begin{align}
  \frac{S(z) - S_0}{z}
    &= S(z) + T(z) \\
  \frac{T(z) - T_0}{z}
    &= \frac{S(z) - S_0}{z} + T(z)
 \end{align}$

Plug in initial values $T_0 = 1, S_0 = 0$ and solve:

$\begin{align}
   S(z)
     &= \frac{z}{1 - 3 z + z^2} \\
   T(z)
     &= \frac{1 - z}{1 - 3 z + z^2}
\end{align}$

Next step is to split into partial fractions (ugly, quadratic irrationalities) and read off the coefficients.